# PHP arrays simplicity in C#

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I worked with PHP and I make very huge use of its dynamic arrays.

Now I'm working with c# and I'm searching something similar.

This is the point:

I make a query in a Database and it return me a recordset with 5 fields:

- Name person
- date
- type shift
- number of shift
- minutes of work

I want to create on the fly an multidimensional array like this

(PHP CODE)

in `$rs` I have one record of my recordset

```
arrWork = array();

arrWork[$rs["Name"]][$rs["Date_shift"]][$rs["type_shift"][$rs["shift"]] += rs["minute_work"];
```

As you know in 1 line I create all dimension of array.

In C#, I have to do this with Hashtables, but I have to check every level, and I think is very time expensive to manage this.

Is there any way to have simplicity of php arrays in C#?

Comment: Not 100% on what the question is but I'll have a go. `string[] arrWork = new string[] { rs.Name, (DateTime)(rs.Date_shift).ToShortDateString(), rs.type_shift, (rs.shift + rs.minute_work).ToString() };` This populates the array on instantiation with the values given. It is automatically given dimensions equalling the size of the data you put in

Comment: Keep in mind that `C#` is a language to be compiled, `PHP` is a language to be interpreted. Performance wise, it makes a huge difference.

Comment: `php arrays simplicity in c#` is not a good question. I think you mean something like `fastest/most elegant way to create a multi-dimensional array in c#?`

Comment: Thanks Alfie, the problem is not only create, but modify existing elements, as you notice the += means that if doesn't already exist the array it will create, but if the combination of name/date/type/shift already exist and have a value , the new value is summed with the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alot of C# programmers actually *like* the declarative syntax and type-safety of the language. I don't think there's an answer that will completely satisfy your needs.

I gave it a shot though :)

```
public class ValueOrDictionary : IDictionary<object, ValueOrDictionary>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<object, ValueOrDictionary> storage = new Dictionary<object, ValueOrDictionary>();
    private object value;
    private bool isValue = false;

    public ValueOrDictionary this[object key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (isValue)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            ValueOrDictionary subLevel;
            if (!storage.TryGetValue(key, out subLevel))
            {
                subLevel = new ValueOrDictionary();
                storage[key] = subLevel;
            }

            return subLevel;
        }
        set
        {
            storage[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            isValue = value != null;
        }
    }

    // ... rest of IDictionary<,> implementation
```

You could then use this as below:

```
ValueOrDictionary arr = new ValueOrDictionary();
arr["a"]["b"].Value = 8;
int myvalue = (int)arr["a"]["b"].Value;
```

This way each "level" in the dictionary doubles as a "value container".

In the end you may win some time when first writing your application, but I think you'll spend alot more time maintaining the application because your compiler can no longer help you determine the type of each value.

It would also be alot harder getting help with your phpc# code from your colleagues or here on SO, if you hang on to what you're currently used to.

Comment: Thank you, your example is very interesting, I will try it. Anyway for the moment I use to check every level using hashtables...